# Is there any way to restrict mixins as to compatible classes?

Tags: qooxdoo

Let's say I want to define a new mixin that extends qx.ui.basic.Atom capabilities. This mixin will have functionality that applies only to qx.ui.basicAtom and it's subclasses an'd doesn't make sense for other classes. Is there any way to restrict the mixing to be allowed only to qx.ui.basic.Atom subclasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I found it. In the mixin constructor we can do

```
construct: function (){
    if (qx.core.Environment.get("qx.debug")) {
        this.assertInstance(this, qx.ui.basic.Atom, "Error: This mixin can be included only in instances of qx.ui.basic.Atom")
    }
},
```

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing. The only thing to dislike is probably that this is a run time check, so you won't get warned at compile time. - Don't forget to accept your own anser :-).